# Basis for Special linear group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I'm looking for basis for the tangent space $T_eSL_2(R)$ of the real special linear group $SL_2(R)$. I only know that group have $X$ matrices with $Trace(X)=0$. How can I do that? Any hint? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Gianluca. İs my following solution way true? Take $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{pmatrix}$ element of $sl_2(R)$ and show that matrices given you are basis.

Comment: Exactly! Every matrix depends on 3 parameters $a,b,c$. Take $a=1, b=c=0$, $b=1, a=c=0$, $c=1, b=a=0$. This gives you a basis.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent space $T_e SL_2\Bbb R \cong \mathfrak{sl}_2$ which is the following algebra over $\Bbb R$:

$$\{ X\in M_2\Bbb R: \text{tr}X=0\}$$

Now it easy to see that a basis is given by

\begin{pmatrix}
0&1 \\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&-1
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Thank you Gianluca. İs my following solution way true?